# How to listen for a didSelectRowAtIndexPath change in another view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'd like to listen/detect a `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` change in `viewController1` and then based on this selection change something in `viewController2`.

Any idea how I might go about doing this?

Comment: use NSNotificationCenter and post a custom notification from viewController1 and add viewController2 as an observer for this notification.

Comment: do you whant do this without recharge (realloc and show) viewController2?

Comment: You will need a Delegate. There should be plenty of resource of how to get one working. If your manipulating data maybe you just want a Helper with static methods and have both viewControllers working off it.

Comment: There are several ways of doing that. A delegare (properly defined using a protocol) is one. Using the notification centre is a more modern approach. Less elegant but effective is simply accessing viewController2 mehtods/properties from viewController1. So what have you tried so far?

Comment: @HermannKlecker So I need to post a Notification for a didSelectRowAtIndexPath: in viewController1 and then listen for that Notification in viewController2?

Comment: Would recommend not to use notifications for this - Notifications by nature are for 1->Many flows and this one is 1->1.

Comment: @HermannKlecker I have a question, is using NSNotificationCenter consider breaking the mvc paradigm?

Comment: using NSNotificationCenter does not break the MVC pattern, it's one of the ways that the model communicates with the controller

Comment: Never thoght of this. I do not think so. Why shoudn't one controller receive messages from another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a KVO.

First create a @property in ViewController1.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath;
```

In ViewController1.m:

```
@synthesize selectedIndexPath;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath!=self.selectedIndexPath) self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath; //this will fire the property changed notification
```

In ViewController2.m, assuming you have a reference to ViewController1 (i.e. vc1) already, set up the Observer in your viewDidLoad:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [vc1 addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedIndexPath" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
     //other stuff
```

and lastly add the following somewhere in ViewController2

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    //inspect 'change' dictionary, fill your boots

    ...
}
```

eta:

You must also remove the observer in ViewController2's dealloc:

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [vc1 removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedIndexPath"];
    ...
}
```